# Qt model for chat widget

Tags: qt, model

I need to create a chat widget for communication with toy satellite. The satellite can send a child text or a picture, while a child can send only text.

I am programming this app on Qt, but stuck with proper model creation. Sure it have to be a list model, but in my case I've got two types of messages (picture or text) and also some additional data, like date and location (last only in messages from satellite).

What class I better to subclass or use as is for my task? Is standard model?enough or I need to subclass list abstract model?

Also I red, that some customization can be done even inside a model, like font color and so on. I am just wondering, is it a right place for it, or I better set background color of messages in delegate?

Just to mention, this class will be then used in a qml.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way for you is to go with **QTreeWidget()**

Comment: But I don't have any hierarchy. How am I should use it?